# Optimize large numbers of matrix multiplications from dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication, euler-angles

I am writing a code to compute the Angle of Attack and Angle of Side Slip of an aircraft, based on the aircraft's orientation and global velocity vector. All of my data is housed in a dataframe. To calculate the angles, I first need to determine the aircraft-relative velocity and I do that with this bit of code. From there it is a trivial to get the Angle of Attack and Angle of Side Slip.

This code works, but I feel like I am missing something that would make it run faster. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    # Calculate aircraft component velocities
    df['a11'] = np.cos(df['Pitch']) * np.cos(df['Yaw'])
    df['a12'] = np.cos(df['Pitch']) * np.sin(df['Yaw'])
    df['a13'] = -1 * np.sin(df['Pitch'])
    
    df['a21'] = np.sin(df['Pitch']) * np.sin(df['Roll']) * np.cos(df['Yaw']) - np.cos(df['Roll']) * np.sin(df['Yaw'])
    df['a22'] = np.sin(df['Pitch']) * np.sin(df['Roll']) * np.sin(df['Yaw']) + np.cos(df['Roll']) * np.cos(df['Yaw'])
    df['a23'] = np.sin(df['Roll']) * np.cos(df['Pitch'])
    
    df['a31'] = np.cos(df['Yaw']) * np.cos(df['Roll']) * np.sin(df['Pitch']) + np.sin(df['Roll']) * np.sin(df['Yaw'])
    df['a32'] = np.sin(df['Yaw']) * np.cos(df['Roll']) * np.sin(df['Pitch']) - np.sin(df['Roll']) * np.cos(df['Yaw'])
    df['a33'] = np.cos(df['Roll']) * np.cos(df['Pitch'])
    
    df['Vxx'] = 0
    df['Vyy'] = 0
    df['Vzz'] = 0
    
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        A = [[row['a11'], row['a12'], row['a13']],
              [row['a21'], row['a22'], row['a23']],
              [row['a31'], row['a32'], row['a33']]]
        B = [[row['Vx']], [row['Vy']], [row['Vz']]]
        
        result = list()
        for i in range(len(A)):
            result.append([0])
        
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(1):
                for k in range(len(B)):
                    result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
                    
        df.loc[idx, 'Vxx'] = result[0][0]
        df.loc[idx, 'Vyy'] = result[1][0]
        df.loc[idx, 'Vzz'] = result[2][0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking a question, please read the following announcements to help you get the answers you want through your questions.: [mre]

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for this question.

Comment: Well, you do compute the same (somewhat expensive, trigonometric) things many times. For example, you compute cos(roll) five times.

Comment: Use a profiler. A few first impressions: Reduce repetitive code. If you must loop in pandas use `df.itertuples` which is faster than `df.iterrows`. Use numpy throughout not pandas, as it is all numeric data.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I implemented them all and found that itertuples and per-calculating the trig made incremental gains, (on average 20% improvement). The biggest gain came from instead of using df.loc in the loop, appending the values into a list and then at the end making the new columns in the df. In one case that brought the run time from 3.8s to 0.38 seconds.

Comment: That seems reasonable. For future reference it is also worth noting that `df.loc` is best used for ranges; `df.at` is much faster for single values (there is also a similar `df.iat` as for `df.iloc`)